# How to ruin the environment!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, science

This morning, I woke up and found this strange note that someone must have slid under my door. It's all very confusing to me... Do you know what any of it means?

> **How to ruin the environment!**
>   Start with a rock and add a dash of citrus.
>   Combine it with water to have a retaliation against burning liquid skies.
>   Because of this property it has, you can finally win at musical limbo!
>   Just make the sound of a beverage (which can also be worn) between me and the snake,
>   And you've got your first ingredient!
>
> The second ingredient is quite easy for you to find,
>   Just steal without asking, and claim it as your own.
>   You don't need all of it, only 3 bits at the start,
>   Though it might seem like you need an entire century!
>
> Once you've done all that, you're almost done!
>   Just put the two next to each other, and hit them with a spoon!

Hint:<sub>Added for clarification</sub>

> I found some fine print at the bottom of the note that said both ingredients are found totally separate from each other, but are totally meaningless on their own. Maybe that can help you!

Hint 2:

> Some things are more literal than others.

Hint 3:

> Not all burns are caused by flames.

Hint 4:

> The first ingredient is 6 letters long.

Comment: beverage (which can also be worn) -> cappuccino -> coffee

Comment: For the first three lines, 'whiskey' comes to my mind!

Comment: sounds like mojito to me, but it could be any cocktail

Comment: I'd guess the sound of the beverage is a hiss, which would imply that the beverage itself is a soda of some sort.  Could be [Tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_(soft_drink)), like shirt collar tabs.

Comment: If I had to guess, the first line means "limestone", since "rock" -> stone and "citrus" -> lime. That's all I have.

Comment: @PatG Definitely on the right track!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, here goes. To begin, I agree with Bulldogg6404 that

> Rock + citrus = limestone

is surely correct. But then I think the "burning liquid skies" must be referring to

> acid rain

(I guess this is what hint 3 is about, but in any case it seems far the most obvious interpretation of those words) and then

> there is an obvious connection between musical limbo and acid rain mitigation, via a pun between "base" (opposite of acid) and "bass" (low musical notes/instruments). And you can turn limestone into lime (calcium hydroxide), which is a base and is sometimes added to water as an anti-acid-rain measure.

There is the small difficulty that

> it's not the limestone that's being added to water; you can make lime from limestone but they aren't the same thing. (And it feels a bit weird to explicitly turn "lime" into "limestone" at the start and then turn it back again a line or two later :-).)

but KoA has confirmed in comments that this is what he meant anyway. OK, so the property we're looking for is, then, that of being

> basic

and now we take that word and

> tnsert "the sound of a beverage" into the word "basic", perhaps between "S" (snake) and "I" (me). That makes "bastic", which isn't exactly a word (it seems to have a slang usage that must be derived from the thankfully-mostly-defunct use of "spastic" as a term of abuse, and it was a bit of technobabble in Doctor Who once) -- but maybe that's OK since the two ingredients are meant to be meaningless on their own.

If so, then

> presumably the second ingredient will also be a non-word, and we'll have to combine them somehow, and surely "hit them with a spoon" means "spoonerize". So it'll be BASTIC PL---- giving PLASTIC B---- or something of the kind.

OK, on to the second ingredient. We need something that means "steal without asking" and

> begins with PL. I wondered about PLUNDER but actually more likely, I think, is PLAGIARIZE or PLAGIARISE (which also emcompasses "claim it as your own"), and if we can reduce this to its first *four* letters then we get BASTIC PLAG, hence PLASTIC BAG, which seems like a pretty reasonable answer.

So, why that many letters? Well,

> if you take the number 100 ("a century") and then pretend it's a *3-bit* binary number, that number is four. So that's the number of letters you take from the start of PLAGIARIZE.

So, in case you missed it above, the answer is

> PLASTIC BAG

whose impact on the environment is pretty familiar to us all.

Comment: Oh boy, I definitely didn't think some part through well enough. Assume an unfavourable reaction occurs between the limestone and water :p

Comment: Also note that acid rain isn't partaking in the reaction, it's just the components of water + limestone that can be used "in retaliation" to acid rain

Comment: Should I take that as an endorsement of the second of my "two possible ways forward"?

Comment: (Or the first? Or am I just confused?)

Comment: Musical limbo is correct! (My apologies for making such a mistake in the puzzle)

Comment: Cool. (Still confused by the rest of it, though...)

Comment: Think about the property the (hypothetical) solution would have that lets it win at musical limbo ;)

Comment: Oh, I assumed I had that (namely, it would be a base. Or it would be "basic", but that doesn't suggest musical limbo so effectively). Was that wrong? Anyway, what I'm currently entirely failing to understand is how that is supposed to connect to what follows...

Comment: "Both ingredients [...] totally meaningless on their own."

Comment: "Basic" is right

Comment: So close! Think about 3 *bits* :D

Comment: I'm thinking about it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39884/discussion-between-koa-and-gareth-mccaughan).

Comment: How about reading a "century" as a bit string

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not seeing how it would help. E.g., a "century" might mean 100 bits. *What* 100 bits? The full word we're trying to abbreviate here has 10 letters, which would be less than 100 bits according to most ways of encoding it (or substantially more with some of the less efficient Unicode encodings). and then 3 bits would be, well, just 3 bits, and I don't see how that can give us the four letters we seem to need. I have the feeling I'm missing something really obvious...

Comment: 100 = 4 in binary. I don't know how much that actually helps....

Comment: Perhaps something like `sentry` or `centurion`?

Comment: @Neon612 ding ding ding!

Comment: Neon612, you'll see in the chat that I reached the same conclusion; apparently it's right. I have to admit I still don't find it terribly convincing, but that's an occupational hazard of "enigmatic" puzzles :-).

Comment: As someone who has been hanging out in chat lately, this answer also seems quite appropriate as the subject happens to be a bit of a meme in the PSE community.

Answer (score 5):

**PARTIAL ANSWER** for second paragraph

> Carbon

The second ingredient is quite easy for you to find,

> It's everywhere

Just steal it without asking, and claim it as your own.

> You take it in and out of your body.

You don't need all of it, only 3 bits at the start,

> Maybe it refers to the 3 isotopes of it.

Though it might seem like you need an entire century!

> Century -> 100 -> C (in roman numerals)

Comment: Good answer, but that's not it. We don't steal carbon ;)

Answer (score 5):

I feel like I made some significant headway, but I have hit a wall. I encourage other solvers to try to expand on my answer and see where it takes them.

> Limestone -> Calcium -> **Ca**
>  Ca + H2O = CAHOO [sic] anagram -> ACHOO -> **Sneeze** (retaliation against smoke/smog = burning liquid [oil] skies)
>  Sneeze = S + neeze -> **S (snake) + Knees** (property for winning at Limbo)

Beyond that much, it is pure guessing, because these next ideas don't match up with the previous analysis as far as I can tell.

> Beverage = Tea -> **T** (sound of tea, T-shirt can be worn)
>  "Between me and the snake" = S + T + Knees = **???**

**Please, feel free to look at my analysis and add your own reasoning.**
I also considered

> Knee_s -> Knee + T + S = **Neets**, which is a real slang term, but doesn't really apply anywhere to the rest of the puzzle.

Comment: H2O is HHO rather than HOO.

Comment: I am aware. That's what the [sic] stands for.

Comment: After all, it could be H20 means H and 2 O

Comment: Fair enough. It seems pretty far-fetched to me.

Comment: (I would find it more plausible if the question had said "H2O", but what it actually said was "water" and if "water" can mean "HOO" then anything can mean anything. But of course it's possible that the original questioner made a mistake.)

Comment: When a puzzle is labeled enigmatic, it welcomes the far-fetched.

Comment: And if my use of Ca to represent calcium is correct, then it might make sense to represent the chemical formula of water, as well.

Comment: Good job! A few things you might want to think about... Limestone is made up of more than just Calcium. Chemical formulas aren't necessary to solve the puzzle.

Comment: Science is definitely relevant ;)